# replace values with NA across multiple columns if a condition is met in R

Tags: r, if-statement, replace, dplyr, na

I'm trying to replace values across values with NA across multiple columns if a condition is met.

Here's a sample dataset:

```
library(tidyverse)
sample <- tibble(id = 1:6,
                 team_score = 5:10,
                 cent_dept_test_agg = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6),
                 cent_dept_blue_agg = c(15:20),
                 num_in_dept = c(1, 1, 2, 5, 100, 6))
```

I want the columns that contain cent_dept_.*_agg to be NA when num_in_dept is 1, so it looks like this:

```
library(tidyverse)
solution <- tibble(id = 1:6,
                   team_score = 5:10,
                   cent_dept_test_agg = c(NA, NA, 3, 4, 5, 6),
                   cent_dept_blue_agg = c(NA, NA, 17:20),
                   num_in_dept = c(1, 1, 2, 5, 100, 6))
```

I've tried using replace_with_na_at (from the **nanier** package) and na_if (from the **dplyr** package), but I can't figure it out. I know my selection criteria is correct (dplyr::matches("cent_dept_.*_agg"), but I can't figure out the solution.

In my actual dataset, I have many columns that start with cent_dept and end with agg, so it's very important that the selection users that matches component.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `mutate_at` to select the columns that `matches` 'cent_dept' and `replace` the values where 'num_in_dept' is 1

```
library(dplyr)
sample %>%
    mutate_at(vars(matches('^cent_dept_.*_agg$')), ~ 
                  replace(., num_in_dept == 1, NA))
# A tibble: 6 x 5
#     id team_score cent_dept_test_agg cent_dept_blue_agg num_in_dept
#  <int>      <int>              <dbl>              <int>       <dbl>
#1     1          5                 NA                 NA           1
#2     2          6                 NA                 NA           1
#3     3          7                  3                 17           2
#4     4          8                  4                 18           5
#5     5          9                  5                 19         100
#6     6         10                  6                 20           6
```

---

In `base R`, we can also do

```
nm1 <- grep('^cent_dept_.*_agg$', names(sample))
sample[nm1] <- lapply(sample[nm1], function(x) 
         replace(x, sample$num_in_dept == 1, NA))
```

Or it can be done with

```
sample[nm1] <-  sample[nm1] * NA^(sample$num_in_dept == 1)
```