# Replace certain values across multiple columns, before column values change, with NA in R

Tags: r, dataframe, rows, na, data-wrangling

I have a dataframe like this:

```
dat <- data.frame(Target = c(rep("01", times = 8), rep("02", times = 5), 
                             rep("03", times = 4)),
                         targ2clicks = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0 ,0 , 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1,
                                         0, 0, 0, 1),
                  targ2midclicks = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0 ,0 , 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1,
                                     1, 0, 0, 1),
                  targ2rClicks = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0 ,0 , 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1,
                                  1, 1, 1, 1))

    Target targ2clicks targ2midclicks targ2rClicks
1      01           1              1            0
2      01           1              1            0
3      01           1              1            0
4      01           1              1            1
5      01           0              0            0
6      01           0              0            0
7      01           0              0            0
8      01           1              1            1
9      02           1              1            0
10     02           0              0            0
11     02           0              0            0
12     02           0              0            0
13     02           1              1            1
14     03           0              1            1
15     03           0              0            1
16     03           0              0            1
17     03           1              1            1
```

I want to write some code that detects whether the first row for each target in the remaining 3 columns is a 1, and if so, replaces all occurrences of '1' before the first 0 with 'NA'. However, I want it to do this individually for all 3 columns, i.e. using OR logic instead of AND. Here is what I would like to end up with:

```
    Target   targ2clicks  targ2midclicks targ2rClicks
1      01          NA             NA            0
2      01          NA             NA            0
3      01          NA             NA            0
4      01          NA             NA            1
5      01           0              0            0
6      01           0              0            0
7      01           0              0            0
8      01           1              1            1
9      02          NA             NA            0
10     02           0              0            0
11     02           0              0            0
12     02           0              0            0
13     02           1              1            1
14     03           0             NA           NA
15     03           0              0           NA
16     03           0              0           NA
17     03           1              1           NA
```

This post is related and expands upon a previous one found here:
[Remove rows of a certain value, before values change in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72732054/remove-rows-of-a-certain-value-before-values-change-in-r)
There is also a similar post here which I am struggling to adapt to my own needs: [replace values with NA across multiple columns if a condition is met in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59699567/replace-values-with-na-across-multiple-columns-if-a-condition-is-met-in-r)

Here is what I have attempted so far, but is not quite right:

```
library(naniar)
dat1 <- dat %>%
  group_by(Target) %>%
  replace_with_na_if(.predicate = c(dat$targ2clicks[1]==1 | dat$targ2midclicks[1]==1 | dat$targ2rClicks[1]==1),
                   condition = cumany(~.x) == 0)
```

This gives me a warning: `Error in probe(.x, .p) : length(.p) == length(.x) is not TRUE`

Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is something you can try using `cumall`. This effectively will convert values not equal to zero to `NA` until the first zero. This logic will give the same results as desired above. However, if your actual needs differ or you want to explicitly check the first row for a given `Target` to ensure is equal to 1, you can change to `first(.) == 1 & cumall(. != 0)` instead.

```
library(tidyverse)

dat %>%
  group_by(Target) %>%
  mutate(across(.cols = starts_with("targ2"), 
                ~replace(., cumall(. != 0), NA)))
```

**Output**

```
   Target targ2clicks targ2midclicks targ2rClicks
   <chr>        <dbl>          <dbl>        <dbl>
 1 01              NA             NA            0
 2 01              NA             NA            0
 3 01              NA             NA            0
 4 01              NA             NA            1
 5 01               0              0            0
 6 01               0              0            0
 7 01               0              0            0
 8 01               1              1            1
 9 02              NA             NA            0
10 02               0              0            0
11 02               0              0            0
12 02               0              0            0
13 02               1              1            1
14 03               0             NA           NA
15 03               0              0           NA
16 03               0              0           NA
17 03               1              1           NA
```